# Spray Json `RootJsonFormat`'s Invariance?

Tags: scala, spray

Given the following:

```
scala> trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case class Boy(name: String) extends Parent
defined class Boy

scala> case class Girl(id: Int) extends Parent
defined class Girl
```

I tried to define an implicit formatter (de-serialization and serialization) for them:

```
scala> object Formats extends DefaultJsonProtocol { 
     |   implicit val format: RootJsonFormat[Parent] = jsonFormat1(Boy.apply)
     |   implicit val girlFormat: RootJsonFormat[Parent] = jsonFormat1(Girl.apply)
     | }
```

But I got compile-time errors:

```
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : spray.json.RootJsonFormat[Boy]
 required: spray.json.RootJsonFormat[Parent]
Note: Boy <: Parent, but trait RootJsonFormat is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
         implicit val format: RootJsonFormat[Parent] = jsonFormat1(Boy.apply)
                                                                  ^
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : spray.json.RootJsonFormat[Girl]
 required: spray.json.RootJsonFormat[Parent]
Note: Girl <: Parent, but trait RootJsonFormat is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
         implicit val girlFormat: RootJsonFormat[Parent] = jsonFormat1(Girl.apply)
                                                                      ^
```

As I understand this compile-time error message, `RootJsonFormat` is invariant is its type parameter.

Why is that?

Comment: Because it is both a `JsonReader` and a `JsonWriter`. A `JsonReader` could be covariant and a `JsonWriter` could be contravariant (they aren't because there were problems with implicit resolution doing that IIRC). In any case this means that a `JsonFormat` must be invariant because it can both accept and produce `T`.

Comment: So, what the error says translated to your scenario is: no, a `JsonFormat[Boy]` is not a `JsonFormat[Parent]` because that would mean that it could translate *all kinds of parents* to json, which it cannot do because it can only write boys.

Comment: Writing a `JsonFormat ` for a hierarchy is a bit awkward in spray-json. You need to define json formats for all the subclasses (e.g. using `jsonFormat1`) and then write the parent `JsonFormat` manually. The parent `JsonFormat` usually needs to implement some way of distinguishing incoming json data to decide which kind of class to read.

Comment: thanks, @jrudolph. Care to post as an answer?